# POST Ant Design Upload file with axios to django ImageField

Tags: django, reactjs, post, axios, antd

How can i send Ant Design Upload file into my Django backend model ImageField. I am using axios to use PUT method as updating users profiel. At the moment i set my image into state and access file object to send it to my backend. This however throws 404 error. Should i somehow change my file data before POSTing it or what could be issue here?

File where i post:

```
state = {
    file: null,
};
    
handleImageChange(file) {
        this.setState({
          file: file
        })
        console.log(file)
    };

handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
        const email = event.target.elements.email.value;
        const location = event.target.elements.location.value;
        const image = this.state.file;
        const sport = this.state.sport;
        axios.defaults.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: this.props.token
        }
        const profileID = this.props.token
        axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/${profileID}/update`, {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            location: location,
            sport: sport,
            image: image,
            })
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.err(error));
        }
```

when i console.log(file), i can correctly see my file that i have uploaded, but i think sending it causes error

Comment: urls.py needed !

Comment: urls are correct

Comment: for update- path('profile/<pk>/update', ProfileViewUpdate.as_view(), name='profile-update'),

Comment: I needed the full urls.py. I read : your url is /api/profile/ and in urls.py just  'profile/' is it normal ?

Comment: url is correct.

Comment: you hit a 404 and say url is correct ? keep your secrets then

Comment: Sorry, it is 400 Error. My url should be correct, it is something else to do with image upload.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "Content-Type" to `"Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

Ant Design (version 4.X) Workable example.

```
const formData = new FormData();    
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);    
const authConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Token ${userTokens.access}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    }


const handleUpload = async () => {
   
    await axios.post('/upload-employees/', formData, authConfig)
        .then(() => {
            setFile([]);
            message.success('upload successfully.');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            message.error('upload failed.');
        })
};

const props = {
    beforeUpload: (file) => {
        console.log(file);
        setFileCSV(file);
        return false;
    },
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
        formData.append('file_name_atr_here', file);
    }
}, [file])
```

JSX for this code

```
<>
    <Upload {...props} maxCount={1}>
        <Button>Select File</Button>
    </Upload>

    <Button
        name={'file_name_atr_here'}
        onClick={handleUpload}
        disabled={!file}
    >
        Start Upload
    </Button>
</>
```